# adb tap and show touch at the same time

Tags: android, touch, settings, adb

I want to make tutorials for my app in different languages. Therefore I write some batch files that use adb to execute a predefined user input.

I enable the show touch feature in the developer settings and this gives some visual feedback if I manually click on the screen but it does not give any feedback if I create the touches over adb like following for example:

```
adb shell input tap 100 200
```

Is there a way to create click/touch events AND give some visual feedback for these events?